# Encountering a 5.5.4 Invalid Address when connecting to a mail relay with python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am using the following code to connect to a mail relay. This mail relay does not require authentication.

```
import smtplib

port=25
smtp_server="smtp.mymailrelay.net"
sender="system.admin@mycompany.com"
receiver="me@mycompany.com"
message = "THIS IS A TEST"

with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
```

I can run this code on several other systems using python 3.9 (or 3.6) successfully. When I run it on this particular system, I get the following error:

```
(env39) [user@systemname test_emailissues]$ python3 ./test_send.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/demo/test_emailissues/./test_send.py", line 11, in <module>
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 867, in sendmail
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 609, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    raise SMTPHeloError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPHeloError: (501, b'5.5.4 Invalid Address')
```

I can run simple mail commands or telnet and connect to this mail relay. From this particular system, this script (and another similar one) just fails. It was working rigorously up until 2 or 3 days ago.

5.5.4 indicates that perhaps there is an issue with a FQDN?

How would you recommend I further diagnose this issue?

Comment: Bad HELO. Make sure the hostname of the system is set properly!

Comment: My hostname is "mycomputer.local." I assume that the ".local." might be the culprit